# Is there anyway to get increased resolution for mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, mouse

I'm currently using canvas.onmousemove to keep track of the mouse position for a drawing application and the resolution (especially when moving fast) is contributing to some problems. Is there any way to get more frequent updates on mouse position?

Comment: probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258424/how-to-set-mousemove-update-speed

Answer (score 0):

Connect the points with lines - this is how most, if not all, other painting programs do it.